# C# AviFile: fccHandler -> codec name?

Tags: c#, .net, codec

Hoping to avoid using any 3rd party utilities. Looking for a way to convert or somehow translate the '`fccHandler`' code contained in `Avi.AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS` into a human-readable codec name for display purposes.

Through a lot of head-scratching and staring at the numbers, I started playing around with it until I remembered reading something about it being uint's representing hex.

This converts properly. :)

```
    public string MakeFourCC(uint fccHandler)
        {
        string inputHex = fccHandler.ToString("X");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i <= inputHex.Length - 2; i += 2)
            {
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(Int32.Parse(inputHex.Substring(i, 2),
            System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))));
            }
        char[] array = sb.ToString().ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(array);
        return new string(array);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code can be used to get a string representation of FOURCC:

```
uint fourcc = ...;
var fourccString = new string
    (
        new[]
        {
            (char)(fourcc & 0xFF),
            (char)((fourcc & 0xFF00) >> 8),
            (char)((fourcc & 0xFF0000) >> 16),
            (char)((fourcc & 0xFF000000U) >> 24)
        }
    );
```

To get more user-friendly name, you can use the list of known FOURCCs http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php